# How to remove the drop-down icon in input element with list attribute?

Tags: css, html

In HTML5, `<input>` element has a new attribute `list`, when I add this attribute there will auto add a drop-down icon. How can I change the style of this icon or just remove it.

Also, I want an action that `<input>` element be focused but no text inputted, all the element in `<datalist>` be showed, how to achieve it?

```
<input list="test-list" type="text">
<datalist id="test-list">
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
    <option value="3"></option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: What kind of browser do you use?

Comment: I use Chrome, but I want it not only solved on Chrome but also Firefox, and maybe ie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the peusdo-element `::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator`:

```css
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input list="test-list" type="text">
<datalist id="test-list">
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
    <option value="3"></option>
</datalist>
```

However, it's worth mentioning that `<datalist>` has [**ridiculously bad support**](http://caniuse.com/#search=datalist), so you'd probably be better off just using a simple `<select>`, which allows for styling through use of `background`:

```css
select {
  width: 268px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 34px;
  background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png) no-repeat right #ddd;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-position-x: 244px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="0" selected="selected">Browser</option>
  <option value="1">IE</option>
  <option value="2">Firefox</option>
  <option value="3">Opera</option>
  <option value="4">Safari</option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I want the input not just limited in what I provide, which cannot be done with `<select>`.

Comment: I appreciate that allowing the users to pick their own value is incredibly useful; there's certainly a trade-off in either of the two approaches. One way to ensure compatibility while allowing for both suggested options and custom options would be to utilise a regular `<select>`, with an 'other' option, which when triggered would reveal a new `<input>`. Though that would be a different design ;]

Comment: That's a ragular way, but I think it is inconvient to users, they need two or more clicks for one input. I used to use angular, that's so easy to achieve this function that this is my first time realize it's hard on original html&css. Maybe I need to think about develop and package this kind of function myself.